# Memory leaks using shared_mutex

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, c++17, mutex

The following code leads into an increasing usage of memory:

```
#include <shared_mutex>

class foo
{
public:
   void bar()
   {
      std::unique_lock lock(m_mtx);
   }
   std::shared_mutex m_mtx;
};

int main()
{
   while (1)
   {
      foo obj;
      obj.bar();
   }
}
```

The following do not: (only changes the mutex type)

```
#include <mutex>

class foo
{
public:
   void bar()
   {
      std::unique_lock lock(m_mtx);
   }
   std::mutex m_mtx;
};

int main()
{
   while (1)
   {
      foo obj;
      obj.bar();
   }
}
```

I am using Windows 7 and using the task manager to track the memory consumption of my program.

I compile with mingw and this simple command line to compile:

```
g++.exe -std=c++17 -o mytest main.cpp
```

What i am doing wrong with the usage of shared_mutex ?

Comment: You need to add more details than just that. In particular, how do you measure memory consumption, what's your platform, etc

Comment: I added the informations

Comment: Doesn't look like MinGW even has standard threading library. How are you able to use it then? Are you using some external library? You should post this information too. Post FULL code you are using (you should have `#include` directives in your source).

Comment: @PlanteVerte I would try a C++ profiler Deleaker/Valgrind/whatever to understand the memory usage. But I just tried your code in Visual Studio 2019 and memory consumption is not growing, it's stable ~25 Mb.

Comment: @Artem Razin thanks for your participation, i will investigate around profiler, i never used one before.

Comment: @StaceyGirl Mingw64, I imagine.

Comment: "Increasing usage of memory" -- how high have you measured it?  What values/columns exactly?

Answer (score 1):

Found it! Quite an old post, don't known if it's still relevant for you.

The problem seems to be using g++, mingw64 and the `std::shared_mutex` (at least version 12-posix).

In fact, there is a memory leak in the C++ library using the standard header file, `<shared_mutex>`. The `pthread_rwlock_destroy` is not called when `PTHREAD_RWLOCK_INITIALIZER` is used to initialize the mutex. However, `pthread_rwlock_destroy` is called as expected when using the `pthread_rwlock_init` version.

I found a way around and a fix. The easy way is to "disable" the constant initializer `PTHREAD_RWLOCK_INITIALIZER` from your source code; this forces the C++ library to call the `pthread_rwlock_init` function, then the `pthread_rwlock_destroy` function. To do that, just insert an `#undef` between `#include <pthread>` and `#include <mutex>`:

```
#include <thread>
#undef PTHREAD_RWLOCK_INITIALIZER
#include <mutex>
#include <shared_mutex>
```

The proper way is to patch the `<shared_mutex>` header file of the C++ standard library and call the `pthread_rwlock_destroy` function in the `shared_mutex` destructor, even if the constant initializer `PTHREAD_RWLOCK_INITIALIZER` is used.

If I find the way to and the time, I will submit a regular patch for the standard `<shared_mutex>` header file.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This seems like a bug in winpthreads. The INITIALIZER macro should not exist if destroying the mutex requires a function call. Either you need a function call to create it *and* destroy it, or you use the initializer macro and don't need to do anything to destroy it.